# Is there a specific name for the arpeggio symbol?

Tags: notation, terminology

Is there a specific name for the squiggly arpeggio symbol? If so, are there different names for arpeggio symbols that point up or down or spans both clefs?

I find having to write out "arpeggio symbol" so much gets old, but I'm guessing there isn't a better way.

This does seem like a pointless question, but some symbols have their own names aside from the names of what they stand for.

Comment: Both Wikipedia and Dolmetsch  just call this the 'arpeggio' or 'broken chord' symbol. I'm not sure what you're after -- e.g. what would you call a quarter rest other than "quarter rest symbol" ?

Comment: @Carl It does seem like an odd question, but I was thinking this might be similar to a coda or other symbol that uses a foreign word.

Comment: This is the relevant internal documentation from the ultimate music engraver, lilypond: http://www.lilypond.org/doc/v2.19/Documentation/notation/expressive-marks-as-lines#arpeggio Nowhere do they call the line anything else than "arpeggio".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbol is just called an arpeggio as you can see here on [Dolmetsch where it is specifically called an arpeggio sign](http://www.dolmetsch.com/musictheory23.htm#arpeggio).

This may seem odd, but there are many examples of this. You would play staccato on a staccato mark, you play a note accented when there is an accent mark, you use your pedal when there is a pedal mark.